# How do I unstage/delete files that have been deleted in the remote Git repo?

Tags: git

I have seen multiple questions about how to remove file that have been deleted locally from the remote repo, but my question is the reverse.
Some files were moved/deleted in the remote repo, I want to delete the corresponding files from my local repo too. How do I do this?

E.g.:

My root has directories `foo`, `bar` and `baz`. A remote commit moved `bar` and `baz` to a new directory `archive`. Now when I pull, I have `foo`, `archive` (with the two new directories under it), `bar` and `baz`.

Comment: Doesn't `git pull` do this for you?

Comment: Nope, it keeps the local files intact.

Comment: Hmm, it definitely should. Can you give a concrete example of this happening?

Comment: my root has directories `foo`, `bar` and `baz`
A remote commit moved `bar` and `baz` to a new directory `archive`
now when i pull, I have `foo`, `archive`(with the two new directories under it) , `bar` and `baz`

Comment: Are there any files in `/bar` or `/baz` after the `git pull`?

Comment: @ScottWeldon The directories are not empty. I ended up doing what Joey Wood suggested below and manually deleted the directories

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
git fetch origin
git reset --hard origin/master
```

Assuming you're in the origin branch and want to sync with master

Answer (score 2):

Use `git clean` to remove untracked directories, I believe `git pull` will delete files but not empty directories.

Try:

```
git clean -fd
```